# Duplicate HTTP requests from Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am using a SMS web service, which sends me the replies to SMS via HTTP Post (i cant change this)

I catch the replies like this:

```
            string from = Request.QueryString["from"];
            string message = Request.QueryString["message"];
            string reference = Request.QueryString["ref"];                
            Database.DBLayer db = new Database.DBLayer(App_Code.ConfigClass.ConnectionString);
            db.InsertReply(Convert.ToInt32(reference), from, message);
```

But it seems to intermittently send me duplicates.. Is there a way of checking if the HTTP Request is a duplicate and if it is not actioning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hash the useful information in the response (e.g. the "from", "message", and "ref" concatenated together).

Use that as a unique constraint in your database.

Answer (score 0):

If `ref` uniquely identifies the message then you could check that such an ID has not been seen before inserting the message.  Might even be worth adding a unique constraint on this field in the database.

Comment: its a reference to the Original SMS message receveid.. However they might send multiple replies to the 1 SMS. therefore it cant be unique.. its just the original msg in the thread

Comment: Then how can you tell the difference between a duplicate message sent by your web service, and the user truly sending the same message twice (which is not impossible)?  Do you have access to any other message attributes (eg. timestamp)? If not, and you really do want to disregard all duplicate responses (whether legitimate or not) then Eric's answer is the way to go.

Comment: This is how I was going to do it. However I thought there may be a way to check for duplicate HTTP requests.. I will stop it in the DB layer.